# Is a tournament with an entry fee and first- and second-prize money gambling?

Tags: halal-haram, gambling

My friends invited me to participate in a football tournament (FIFA) competition. A participant will have to pay 200 [taka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangladeshi_taka) (less than $US 3) for entering. The winner will get 600 taka and the runner up will get 350 taka. Since there is a matter of money and a possibility of losing the money, I am quite unsure about my participation.

I want to know whether these types of competitions are permissible or not. Is it a type of gambling or not?

Comment: Gambling is the wagering of money or something of value (referred to as "the stakes") on an event with an UNCERTAIN OUTCOME with the primary intent of winning money or material goods. See here,  http://www.google.co.in/url?q=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambling&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiC9N6hy4rWAhXFwI8KHUiZDYQQFggPMAE&usg=AFQjCNEgB6o-MhWkKzLiq7a0IZyqoV_vNg

Comment: Does "competition" entail actually having to win a football match?

Comment: Related: [Is giving prize money on an Islamic quiz considered gambling?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43244/17163)